# js regexp floating number with leading zero

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, qregexp, qregularexpression

I need to make an input mask that meets the following requirements:

1. 1255454 - ok
2. 1.54546 - ok
3. 1,0056 - ok
4. 0.6565 - ok
5. 0,0056 - ok
6. 056565 - not ok
7. ds5asd - not ok
8. .0565656 - not ok

so far I have found this solution:
"/^-?\d*[.,]?\d*$/.test(value)"
but it doesn't cover these cases: ".0565656" and "056565"

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Предлагаю попробовать такое регулярное выражение:

```
/^([1-9]|-?\d[.,])\d*$/
```

Comment: Зачем вы отвечаете на вопрос на английском языке?

Comment: К тому же выражение не работает на всех примерах из вопроса, поэтому минус